# Angular post request sends [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in angular and I'm working on an angular 6 / Spring Boot 2 project. I have this TypeScript class:

```
export class Partner {

  constructor
  (
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public email: string,
    public phone: string,
    public address: string,
    public picture: string,
    public latitude: number,
    public longitude: number,
    public horary: string,
    public comment: string,
    public specialOffer: boolean,
    public offer: string,
    public location: Location,
    public tripAdvisorLink: string,
    public type: Type,
    public country: string,
    public hotWords: HotWord[],
  ) {}
}
```

So, for example I would like to create a partner and I need to choose a `Location`.

In my HTML I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="partner_location" class="form-control-label" required>Choose location <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <select id="partner_location" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="partner.location" name="partner_location">
    <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location">{{location.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And in my create partner component:

```
export class CreatePartnerComponent implements OnInit {

  partner = new Partner(undefined, '', '', '', '', '', undefined, undefined, '', '', false, '', null, '', null, '', null);
  types: Type[];
  locations: Location[];
  message = '';
  error = '';

  constructor(
    private getPartnersService: GetPartnersService,
    private getTypesService: GetTypesService,
    private getLocationService: GetLocationsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadInitialData();
  }

  loadInitialData() {
    this.getLocationService.getLocations().subscribe(locations => this.locations = locations);
    this.getTypesService.getTypes().subscribe(types => this.types = types);
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Partner = ' + JSON.stringify(this.partner));
    this.getPartnersService.createPartner(this.partner)
      .subscribe(partner => {
        if (partner.id !== undefined) {
          this.showMessage();
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } else {
          this.showError();
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
      });
  }
```

and this my create partner method:

```
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}) };

  createPartner(partner: Partner): Observable<Partner> {
    const url = `${baseUrl}/partner/add`;
    return this.http.post<Partner>(url, partner, httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(HandleError.handleError<Partner>('createPartner')));
  }
```

And I'm getting an error in Spring that says that he can't create `Location` from `[Object object]`. And my `console.log('Partner = ' + JSON.stringify(this.partner));` method prints:

```
Partner = {"name":"Test production","email":"v.solodoukhin@outlook.com","phone":"32489836733","address":"brolekestraat","picture":"","latitude":"55","longitude":"1.23424324","horary":"9 - 18 every day","comment":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","specialOffer":true,"offer":"5%","location":"[object Object]","tripAdvisorLink":"http://brol.be","type":"[object Object]","country":"Belgium","hotWords":null}
```

So as far I understand, the http post request sends `location : [object Object]`....

How can do this work ?

Comment: Could you provide us your `Controller` class in Java?

Comment: You problem is on the option value binding. It should be `[ngValue]="location"` instead of `[value]="location"`. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pckh2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data binding sets `partner.location` to a string because the `option` value is bound with `[value]`. You should use `[ngValue]` to bind the `option` value to an object:

```
<select id="partner_location" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="partner.location" name="partner_location">
  <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location">{{location.name}}</option>
</select>
```

---

From the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-select-controls-with-form-directives):

> If your option values are simple strings, you can bind to the normal
>   `value` property on the option. If your option values happen to be
>   objects (and you'd like to save the selection in your form as an
>   object), use `ngValue` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I took `[value]` from guide ( https://angular.io/guide/forms#add-powers-with-ngfor ). Didn't know about [ngValue]...

Comment: You are welcome. The documentation about `[ngValue]` is not so easy to find. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was where you bind the value of the option. The correct binding should be the follow:

```
<option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location">{{location.name}}</option>
```

Check my StackBlitz to see it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pckh2b

Answer (score 0):

[Object object] means that it is not encoded in a readable manner for the file. You have to encode it and decode it.